# Логика написание приложения с возможностью совместного редактирования

Tags: сокет, логика

Изучил подробно работу сокетов, вплоть до практической реализации различных идей на нескольких языках. Теперь возникла задача написать облачный редактор текста. (Совместное редактирование текста) Сел, написал сервер, на котором располагается txt файл. При отправлении на сервер запроса **GET**, сервер возвращает содержимое документа. При любом другом - сервер сохраняет полученные данные в документ.

Начал писать редактор. Сделал простейшую логику: каждую секунду происходит синхронизация файла с сервером. Но, возникла проблема, когда на компьютере А изменяется файл, сервер его принимает, обновляет документ на компьютере Б и одновременно с этим стирает часть текста, которую написал пользователь Б. Либо наоборот.

Разрабатываю приложение в Xcode на c++, могу переделать под swift, но это не так важно. Так все же, как реализовать логику облачного редактирования?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, нужно ввести lsn - linear serial number, ну тупо счетчик. Данная концепция  весьма распространена.
В чем идея?
1) Клиент А при старте редактора запрашивает с сервера lsn. Допустим lsn == 1 в этот момент. Далее клиент А редактирует документ и отправляет на сервер пару: (новый текст, lsn).

2) Сервер сверяет свой lsn с тем, который прислал клиент. Если они совпадают, сервер увеличивает lsn и сохраняет новый текст. Иначе изменения не принимаются - сервер отправляет клиенту А ответ с ошибкой и тем значением lsn, которое в данный момент установлено в сервере.
Важное замечание: сервер должен обновлять lsn атомарно.

3) Что делает А? Если сервер прислал "успех", то все ок - можно редактировать дальше. Если сервер прислал "ошибка" и новый lsn - это значит, что текст на сервере был изменен. Надо загрузить новый текст с сервера, "смержить" этот новый текст с тем, который уже имеется в клиенте А и попытаться вновь выполнить п.1.